# Can't interact with ExoPlayer. Possible focus issue?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, android-tv, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to use ExoPlayer (2.18.7) via an `AndroidView` using Jetpack Compose (1.0.0-alpha06). The video shows up and plays correctly but I can't interact with it at all (D-pad, ok/select, nothing). I tried using a `FocusRequester` but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Here's my VideoPlayer composable:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer(mediaItem: VideoApi.MediaItem) {
    val (playerFocus) = remember { FocusRequester.createRefs() }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()
            .apply {
                addMediaItem(
                    MediaItem.Builder()
                        .setUri(mediaItem.hlsCaptions)
                        .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
                        .build()
                )
                prepare()
                playWhenReady = true
            }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        playerFocus.requestFocus()
    }

    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusable(true)
                .focusRequester(playerFocus),
            factory = {
                StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
                    player = exoPlayer
                    useController = true
                    controllerAutoShow = true
                    setShowBuffering(StyledPlayerView.SHOW_BUFFERING_ALWAYS)
                }
            }
        )
    ) {
        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, key events need to get forwarded to the player. See [here](https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/460#issuecomment-1591354476).